# Not able to insert object into array of json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Excuse me for this simple problem  - but I seem to miss something obvious.Any pointer would be a great help.

I have a JSON like

```
var  whatever = [{           
"key1" : { "text" : "text1","group"  : "1" },
"key2" : { "text" : "text2","group"  : "2" },
"key3" : { "text" : "text3","group"  : "3" }
}];
```

I am trying to add another object(at start preferably) - but just couldn't get it to work.

```
var str = '{"text":"text0","group":"0"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
whatever[0].put("key0",obj);
```

Getting the below error:

`Uncaught TypeError: whatever[0].put is not a function`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soumyazyx/x58c6m28/)

Comment: Object properties do not have an order, so adding it "at the start" makes no sense.

Comment: just a question, why an array?

Comment: The error was pretty clear. Don't take this as being rude, but you should really try harder to understand what the interpreter/compiler tells you. As for javascript opening a console writing 'obj.' shows you completion that are really helpful as a first source of documentation

Comment: @NinaScholz I was trying to order the entries but after going through the replies - I realize that this is not the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `put` function on the object. Use property instead of it. When you want to assign to a property which does not exist, it creates a new one and assigns the value to it.

```
whatever[0]["key0"] = obj;
```

What is related to *at start preferably*, there is no order for object properties. It is a wrong statement. If you want ordering try to think from the view of array of objects instead of array of object, which contains objects.

**Code examples**

```js
const whatever = [{           
   "key1" : { "text" : "text1","group"  : "1" },
   "key2" : { "text" : "text2","group"  : "2" },
   "key3" : { "text" : "text3","group"  : "3" }
}];

const str = '{ "text" : "text0", "group" : "0" }';
const obj = JSON.parse(str);

whatever[0]["key0"] = obj;

console.log(whatever);
```

Or use [**Object#assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const whatever = [{           
   "key1" : { "text" : "text1","group"  : "1" },
   "key2" : { "text" : "text2","group"  : "2" },
   "key3" : { "text" : "text3","group"  : "3" }
}];

const str = '{ "text" : "text0", "group" : "0" }';
const obj = JSON.parse(str);

Object.assign(whatever[0], { key0: obj }) // this will also change the object

console.log(whatever);
```

My suggestion is to use an array of objects, if you want something with order.

```js
const whatever = [
   { "text" : "text1","group"  : "1" },
   { "text" : "text2","group"  : "2" },
   { "text" : "text3","group"  : "3" }
];

const str = '{ "text" : "text0", "group" : "0" }';
const obj = JSON.parse(str);

// Add to the start
whatever.unshift(obj);
console.log(whatever);

// Add to the end
whatever.push(obj);
console.log(whatever);
```

Comment: Technically wrong, "at start preferably" yours will add it to the end. unshift() to append to the front of an array should be used.

Comment: @Adriani6 Didn't look at that part. Edited

Comment: Perfect, Now it's a complete answer.

Comment: Perfect explanation.I stand corrected on the way how to order.I will modify it accordingly straight away.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want something like this

```js
var  whatever = [{           
"key1" : { "text" : "text1","group"  : "1" },
"key2" : { "text" : "text2","group"  : "2" },
"key3" : { "text" : "text3","group"  : "3" }
}];

Object.assign(whatever[0], {key4 : { "text" : "text4","group"  : "4" }});

console.log(whatever);
```